# msg.value in constructor

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.8.x

**solc 0.8.4**

I'm trying to save the value of `msg.value` in my constructor. If I assign it to one of the state variables, it gets reverted by the EVM when I try to deploy the contract. However, if I assign that state variable a non-zero value (either before or after setting it to `msg.value`), then it works.

State variables:

```
address payable contract_owner;
uint256 wei_received;
```

**Constructor version 1**
The `wei_received` state variable is set to 1 before it is set to `msg.value`.
Success: The contract deploys and the value of `wei_received` is set correctly.

```
constructor () payable
{
    contract_owner = payable (msg.sender);
    wei_received = 1;
    wei_received = msg.value;
}
```

**Constructor version 2**
The `wei_received` state variable is not being set to 1.
Failure: Reverted by the EVM at time of deployment.

```
constructor () payable
{
    contract_owner = payable (msg.sender);
    wei_received = msg.value;
}
```

**Constructor version 3**
The `wei_received` state variable is set to 1 after it is set to `msg.value`.
Failure: The contract deploys but the value of `wei_received` is set incorrectly.

```
constructor () payable
{
    contract_owner = payable (msg.sender);
    wei_received = msg.value;
    wei_received = 1;
}
```

Is that by design for some reason? Is it a bug in this version of solidity? The workaround is simple, but I'm wondering if anyone else has noticed this and if there is a reason for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the different scenarios on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.4+commit.c7e474f2.js) and had no issues.

For example for the `constructor version 2` scenario I successfully deployed this contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract B {
    address payable contract_owner;
    uint256 wei_received;
    
   constructor () payable {
    contract_owner = payable (msg.sender);
    wei_received = msg.value;
    } 

    function getReceipt() public view returns (uint256) {
        return wei_received;
    }
}
```

Furthermore I get the correct value for `wei_received` when calling the `getReceipt` function.

With `constructor version 3` I get 1 for `wei_received` which is the expected result.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by increasing my gas limit. I've never seen such bizarre behavior caused by insufficient gas.